# ChromeOptions causes reference error using Selenium ChromeDriver for node.js

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use the ChromeDriver driver for Selenium to run some tests using Chrome, but I'm getting a reference error when I use `ChromeOptions`.

## My Code

I want to force the use of certain options, such as testing it against a particular user profile. Based on the Selenium and ChromeDriver documentation, this is my file `test.js`:

```
opt = new chromeOptions(); // ERROR OCCURS HERE!
opt.setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");
opt.addArguments("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\MyUserAccount\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data");
driver = new ChromeDriver(opt);

// rest of my script goes here
```

## The error

I am executing this using the command `node test.js`. This throws the following error on the first line:

```
\path\to\test.js:1

ction (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { opt = new chromeOpti
                                                                    ^
ReferenceError: chromeOptions is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (\path\to\test.js:1:73)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

For what it's worth, if I skip setting options and replace the first four lines of the script with this, it works, but I can't set the options I need to set:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
    withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).
    build();
```

I'm sure that I'm missing something really basic, but I can't figure this one out.  How can I set options for Chrome using Selenium and node.js?

*Edited to remove some obviously invalid syntax from the samples in some of the documentation I found.*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
var webdriver = require("selenium-webdriver");
var chrome = require("selenium-webdriver/chrome");

// Make sure the PATH is set to find ChromeDriver. I'm on a Unix
// system. You'll need to adapt to whatever is needed for
// Windows. Actually, since you say that you can get a browser to show
// up if you don't try to specify options, your ChromeDriver is
// probably already on your PATH, so you can probably skip this.
process.env["PATH"] += ":/home/user/src/selenium/";

var options = new chrome.Options();

// Commented out because they are obviously not what you want.
// Uncomment and adapt as needed:
//
// options.setChromeBinaryPath("/tmp/foo");
// options.addArguments(["--blah"]);

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
   withCapabilities(options.toCapabilities()).build();

driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```

I've tested the code above with various values and found that it works.

If you want to see what else you can do with the `Options` object, you can open `node_modules/selenium_webdriver/chrome.js` and read the source. This is how I figured out the above method.

Comment: Thanks; this is *really* close. It launches Chrome with the options I am passing to it (i.e., the right profile), but then the `driver.get(...)` and subsequent commands don't seem to do anything. It doesn't actually navigate to google.com, for example. Any thoughts?

Comment: Wow. I've never seen this kind of behavior. When I wrote this answer, my tests were either completely successful or failing *really* early in the process with a useful error message on the console. The only thing that comes to mind immediately is to make sure that you have the latest ChromeDriver installed.

Comment: I installed ChromeDriver just a few days ago and actually reinstalled yesterday. I'll play with this some more, as your answer seems promising.

Comment: Okay, so here's what I figured out: it works if I load a user profile other than my own. It doesn't work if I load my own, even if I try to disable extensions; it just seems to hang up. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Sorry. I don't know. I've never tried to use my own profile. I use Selenium for testing applications, which means the testing environment must be pristine.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm aiming to figure out how to use it for some browser automation, in addition to testing, but this gets me much closer than I have been. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: What can you do with the `capabilities` variable. In your example it is not used ?

Comment: You're right. I probably tried something different initially and forgot to remove the unused variable.

Answer (score 6):

could you please just try below solution

```
var webdriver = require("selenium-webdriver");
var chrome = require("selenium-webdriver/chrome");

/** 
 * Set chrome command line options/switches
*/      
var chromeOptions = new chrome.Options();
chromeOptions.addArguments("test-type");
chromeOptions.addArguments("start-maximized");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--js-flags=--expose-gc");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--enable-precise-memory-info");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-default-apps");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-infobars");

driver = new webdriver.Builder()
             .forBrowser("chrome")
             .setChromeOptions(chromeOptions)
             .build();

driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```

Comment: its not working . I ama useing latest chromedriver version

Answer (score 1):

This works for me (from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/anandsunderraman/e351485319a8a0e7df7e))

```
//import the selenium web driver
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var chromeCapabilities = webdriver.Capabilities.chrome();
//setting chrome options to start the browser fully maximized
var chromeOptions = {
    'args': ['--test-type', '--start-maximized']
};
chromeCapabilities.set('chromeOptions', chromeOptions);
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(chromeCapabilities).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a fundamental OOP JavaScript misunderstanding!

Your problem is:

```
ChromeOptions opts = new chromeOptions();
```

You don't instantiate objects this way.  Try:

```
var opt = new ChromeOptions();
```

Here's proof:
http://jsfiddle.net/q5Etk/

If you run that, we get "Unexpected Identifier".
Uncomment the `var` bit and comment the `Cat cat` bit and see it work.

**EDIT** After your edit:

You are specifying `chromeOptions()`.  It's `ChromeOptions()` capped `C`

Comment: Sorry; I know that syntax doesn't make sense. Nonetheless, it was in a number of samples I found that purported to show JavaScript sample code (some of which were clearly really Java). I actually revised the code to use your suggested version (`var opts = new ChromeOptions();`) and forgot to fix my question. I have revised the question now to reflect the real error.

Comment: Regarding your edit: using `ChromeOptions()` throws exactly the same error.

Comment: What error is that? `'ChromeOptions' is not defined`?

Comment: Yes, exactly; only difference is the capitalization changes when I change my code.

Comment: I don't believe that `ChromeOptions` class is in existence in webdriverjs honestly... a search through the source yielded nothing

Comment: It doesn't seem like it. What's weird is that I have chromedriver installed and in my path, but Node doesn't appear to care. I'm exploring bypassing `ChromeOptions` entirely by passing an argument in this line of the alternate version: `var driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome(/* arg here */)).build();` Problem is, that doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var m_Options = new chrome.Options();   
    m_Options.addArguments("--user-data-dir=C:/Users/israfil/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/Profile 2");
    m_Options.addArguments("--profile-directory=Default");
    m_Options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); 
    m_Options.addArguments(['user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.11 Safari/537.36"']);
    m_Options.setBinaryPath("H://project//nodejs//chrome//chrome.exe");
    m_Options.directConnect = false; //setBinaryPath true;
    
    //m_Options.addExtensions();
    //m_Options.setProxy();
    //m_Options.headless();// Options.headless()}.#headless Options.headless()} Gpu Support ok
    
    //m_Options.addArguments(" --blah"); // not use this codes Importent
    
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).setChromeOptions(m_Options).build();
```

Comment: With no explanation, it’s not clear that this block of code adds anything to the accepted answer from six years ago. Please take time to learn how to use this site before posting answers like this.