# How to instruct Webdriver how to run Chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js, webdriver

I'm using Webdriver with NodeJs and I start things like this

```
 browser = new webdriver.Builder().usingServer().withCapabilities({
            'browserName': 'chrome',
            'reuse_browser': false
        }).build();
```

This starts Chrome. However, I need to start chrome with arguments. Also, I would like to use Chrome Canary, but webdriver starts my regular chrome browser.

How can I do both things with Webdriver ?

Comment: follow this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/22494427/1918648

Comment: Yep, that Post did the trick, thnx. Important for all this is to make sure chrome is not running before you start chrome with specific arguments, otherwise (and I just noticed) it will not work!